# Compare two date columns and then based on difference set a flag in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two datetime columns like shown below,

```
d1  d2
0   2016-07-05  2016-08-15
1   2016-09-14  2016-10-11
2   2016-10-12  2016-11-08
3   2016-11-09  2016-12-06
4   2016-12-07  2017-01-03
5   2017-01-04  2017-02-28
6   2017-03-01  2017-03-28
7   2017-04-03  2017-04-30
8   2017-05-03  2017-05-30
9   2017-06-02  2017-06-29
10  2019-04-25  2019-05-22
```

I want to make anothe column named `flag` based on the condition,

If the last d2 and d1 is seperated by more than 1 day, then set flag as last flag + 1. Otherwise use the same flag. For the first row the flag is always `1`.

The result I am looking for is,

```
0     1
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     3
8     4
9     5
10    6
```

I am using this long code to achieve this,

```
(~test['d1'].sub(test['d2'].shift()).fillna(pd.Timedelta(days=0)).le(pd.Timedelta(days=1))).cumsum() + 1
```

I am worried about the efficency of this line of code. Is there any better alternative I can choose.?

Comment: `(df['d2'].shift() - df['d1']).dt.days.abs().gt(1).cumsum().add(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use shift in combination with assign and cumsum methods. Look at the following code:

```
df = (df
     .assign(d1 = lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d.d1),
             d2 = lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d.d2),
             difference = lambda d: (d.d1-d.d2.shift()).dt.days.abs(),
             flag = lambda d: 1+(d.difference>1).cumsum()))
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Performace seems similar to the code i posted in the Q

Comment: This is the maximum performance you are going to achieve with Pandas, all the operations performed here are vectorised :D. Hope it helps!